# how to get the count of the posts for each month in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

i want to make charts in my laravel application and i want to show how many posts was created in each month so i need a sort of api like below :

```
{
count:22,
month:1-1-2020
},
{
count:18,
month:1-2-2020
}
```

here is what i tried to do :

```
       return Post::all()->groupBy(function($post) { // Get all posts as collection and apply groupBy method
            $post->created_at->format('F'); // ex: September
        });
```

but it didint work to group the counts by the month so is there any way to achive this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try aggregating by `DATE_FORMAT` of your date, with the mask `%Y-%m`:

```
$results = Post::select(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS ym, COUNT(*) AS cnt"))
->groupBy(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m')"))
->get();
```

If your actual database be Postgres, then a similar approach using `TO_CHAR` should work:

```
$results = Post::select(\DB::raw("TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS ym, COUNT(*) AS cnt"))
->groupBy(\DB::raw("TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM')"))
->get();
```

Comment: it gives this error :Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function date_format(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist LINE 1: select

Comment: @Farshad You've tagged your question with MySQL.  Is that really your database, or are you maybe using Postgres?

Comment: Oops yes its postgres sorry i change tag

Comment: yes that will do the trick thanks for that and 1 more question Can i sort them by Date too‌???

Comment: in case any one need this i did that with             ->orderBy('ym') in elequent

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
return Post::select(DB::raw('count(1) AS count'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "01-%m-%Y") AS month'))->groupBy(function($post) { // Get all posts as collection and apply groupBy method
     $post->created_at->format('01-m-Y'); // ex: 01-02-2019
})->get()
```

I hope this will work for you...

Comment: it gives me the below erro stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given